# Shorter condition code of checking each character of a string in Java

Tags: java, string, character

Here is my code to check if each character in the string is a vowel or not

```
if(word.charAt(i) == 'a' || word.charAt(i) == 'e' || word.charAt(i) == 'i' || word.charAt(i) == 'o' 
                    || word.charAt(i) == 'u')
```

Do I have to keep repeating word.charAt(i) for each vowel in Java ? I am repeating it 5 times in the code. Is there a shorter way or am I at the mercy of repeating code when forming my condition for the logic?

Comment: You shouldn't even access individual characters. See my answer for details.

Comment: @laune see my reply to your comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a function and use it everywhere.

```
   public function isVowel(String word, int index){
    return "aeiou".contains(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)));
   }
```

call it as

```
 isVowel(word,i);
```

Answer (score 3):

One short boolean test that springs to my mind is something like

```
"aeiou".contains(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))
```

Comment: This back and forth between string and character isn't necessary. Shorter is: `"aeiou".contains( word.substring(i, i+1) )` but you can test the entire string in one fell swoop...

Comment: @laune What if OP wants to count the number of vowels? I agree your regular expression is nice if OP wants to determine that the entire `String` is composed of vowels but I see nothing in the question to indicate that. Finally, using the `Character.toString()` is already a bit of an optimization (the objective for the OP was shorter code... I could have used `"aeiou".contains("" + word.charAt(i))` which is shorter, **but** ugly).

Comment: Maybe my grasp of English is insufficient, but I understood to "check if each character in the string is a vowel or not" to mean to check that *all* are vowels. Now that an answer has been accepted that returns true if there is a *single* vowel, I'd modify my answer by changing the regex a little...

Comment: @laune OP has specified in the comment to your answer that my WAG was correct and he wanted to count the vowels. Your quote is correct, but again he wants to "test if each character" is a vowel (not whether the `String` is composed entirely of vowels).

Comment: Yes, he's leading us around in circles. Now I've added the third variant: counting.

Comment: I took your line to shorten the code, my answer is marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
String vowel ="aeiou";

if(vowel.contains(word.charAt(i)+"" ) )
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even access individual characters:

```
if( word.matches( "^[aeiou]+$" ) ){
    // all vowels
}
if( word.matches( ".*[aeiou].*" ) ){
    // one vowel
}

int count = word.length() - word.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "").length();
// or
int count = word.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();
```

Comment: but I have to count the number of vowels in a character string. Your code just checks if the string matches the argument passed into the matches method.

Comment: @Nicholas Neither your question nor the answer you selected indicates that you need to count.

Comment: @Nicholas Now I've added counting, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "aeiou".indexOf(word.charAt(i)) < 0 but propably the performance would not be good as yours because an new string created and a look up process on that. I am not sure :D